# Not showing Sidebar Theme Berkeley in xepersian

Tags: beamer, xepersian

% XeLatex

% Not showing Sidebar Theme Berkeley in xepersian!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usetheme{Berkeley}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usepackage{xepersian}
    \settextfont{XB Zar}
    \raggedleft
    \begin{document}
    \section{بخش}
    \subsection{زیربخش}
    \begin{frame}{عنوان}
    تست
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hacks to try to repair beamer sidebar theme for RTL:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}
\raggedleft

\author{names}
\title{text}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=}
\makeatletter

\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}{%
        {\textcolor{structure.fg}{\rule{\beamer@sidebarwidth}{1.1\textheight}}}%
        \vspace{-1.1\textheight}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\hoffset=-\beamer@sidebarwidth
\makeatother   

\section{بخش}
\subsection{زیربخش}


\begin{frame}{عنوان}
عنوان
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{عنوان}
عنوان
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

[image]